# How to start an interactive Python interpreter via Poetry with command line editing enabled

Tags: python, command-line-interface, readline, python-poetry

When I start from the command line a normal Python interpreter via

```
$ python3
```

I get a interactive interpreter with command line editing: [Cursor up] and [Cursor down] go through the history, [Cursor left] and [Cursor right] edit the current line.

Now I have created a virtual environment with [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). Via Poetry's command line tool I can run easily an interactive Python interpreter which uses this virtual environment:

```
cd <project-directory>
poetry run python
```

However this Python interpreter (or `poetry run python3` for that matter) does **not** respond to cursor keys for command line editing.

How can I tell Poetry to instantiate the interpreter **with** command line editing enabled?

Comment: Try with ```poetry run python3```. Probably you are not running same python version. Other possible issue is that some lib like ipykernel is not installed in the new environment

Comment: @DanielArgüelles Thanks for chiming in. I just tried `poetry run python3` and it doesn’t better it. (I guess  `python3` and `python` are symlinks.) - BTW, what is `ipykernel` for? I don’t think that is installed in my normal Python environment…

Comment: If you don't know what is it, you don't needed ;) It is the beckend kernel for jupyter notebooks. I saw some of my colleagues using it, but it seems that that's not your problem. Is `python3` and `poetry run python` running the same python version?